# NullPointerException by called setAdapter in runnable in activity

Tags: java, android

Note: This piece of code works on a fragment in my app.. Same adapter but has getActivity().getApplicationContext() instead of Activity.this.

I'm trying to do the same thing in an activity but I keep getting a NPE on the setAdapter line. Assume the Arraylist item is populated by a different thread.

```
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //test if item Arraylist has stuff in it
                        for (MainGridItem t: item) {
                            System.out.println(t.getUrl()+t.getName()+t.getLinkUrl());
                        }

                        SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, item));
                        swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(activity_grid);

                        assert swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getViewAnimator() != null;
                        swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getViewAnimator().setInitialDelayMillis(DELAY);

                        activity_grid.setAdapter(swingBottomInAnimationAdapter);
```

Comment: where is `activity_grid` initialized

Comment: @InjectView(R.id.activity_grid)
    GridView activity_grid; ->> before onCreate

Comment: looks like `activity_grid` is null. see if its initialized properly

Answer (score 2):

Not related to answer but
It is just knowledge sharing and to resolve worse memory management mistakes

**Avoid dependency injection frameworks**

*As Google official site says.*

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#DependencyInjection

Answer (score 1):

@meowkittycat

With your code snippet i can say the NPE on the "**activity_grid**" object, check whether you intialized the Object in the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I've been working on this for so long today that I didn't see that activity_grid wasn't injected. I apologize for the dumb question and thanks for the tips. I thought for the longest time that it was my adapter or some thread stuff I didn't know.